# TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str

Tags: python, typeerror

I am not understanding where did I possibly go wrong in the below code. It keeps saying range() Integer end argument expected, got str.

```
def test():

    nameList = ["Default", "Customize..."]
    for name in nameList:
             activateFieldsSubMenus(2, name)


def activateFieldsSubMenus(subMenusName,tries=1):

              for i in range(tries):
                 try:
                     mouseClick(waitForObject(":NYSE Connect_DetailedQuoteFieldsPanel"), 42, 13, 4, Button.Button3)
                     menuItem = waitForObjectItem(":NYSE Connect_DetailedQuoteFieldsPanel", "Fields")
                     activateItem(menuItem)
                     subs = object.children(menuItem)
                     for item in subs:
                         if subMenusName in item.text:
                             activateItem(item)

                             break
                         snooze(1)
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback!

Comment: The second argument in function `activateFieldsSubMenus` you give a variable `name`, which is string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
activateFieldsSubMenus(2, name)
```

`name` is a string not an integer, as your list only contains strings.

In your `activateFieldsSubMenus` routine `name`, now called `tries`, is then passed into `range(tries)`.

---

You probably meant to write

```
activateFieldsSubMenus(name, 2)
```

Comment: This Actually helped fix the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `activateFieldsSubMenus` with the 2 parameters mixed up I believe, try:

```
activateFieldsSubMenus(name, tries=2)
```